# How to show pytest-sugar formatting within Python Test Log

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have installed pytest-sugar and tried to use it within VS Code Python (superb!) plugin. It works at terminal when using pytest command. Unfortunately on Python Test Log, it seems pytest-sugar cannot do its tricks. Had anyone else face the same? If so, how to overcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the tricks pytest-sugar does it requires a terminal, not the Output panel as the Python extension uses. There's also a potential issue from the extra output mucking with the pytest discovery code being used for test discovery.

Your best option is to turn off pytest-sugar when using pytest with VS Code. You can either do that by actively turning on the extension when you run at the terminal or turn it off explicitly in VS Code:

```
"python.testing.pytestArgs: ["-p", "no:pytest-sugar"]
```